# When using Popen how can I read from stdout?

Tags: python, subprocess

I'm trying to use `Popen` to start a shell process, execute commands, print the commands to output, and print the output of the commands (if any). Writing to `stdin` is working fine, but trying to read from `stdout` causes the program to freeze.

Here's my program:

```
with Popen(["/bin/sh"], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT, text=True, bufsize=0) as proc:
    with open("script.txt") as scriptFile:
        for line in scriptFile.readlines():
            proc.stdin.write(line)
            print(f"$ {line.strip()}")
            # Reading from proc.stdout locks the program.
            for outputLine in proc.stdout.readlines():
                print(outputLine)
```

And here's a simplified *script.txt*. (The real one creates a git repository and illustrates the use of various git commands.)

```
mkdir project
cd project
echo "This is line 1.\nThis is line 2." > text1.txt
cat text1.txt
```

If I don't try to read from `stdout` all of the commands in *script.txt* (and my real version with multiple git commands) work fine.

Is there any way to get the output of commands from `stdout` interspersed with writing them to `stdin`?

Comment: Is there a reason why you're not just executing the script directly with `/bin/sh script.txt`?

Comment: The problem is that you're trying to read the output before any output has been produced. On the first iteration of the loop, you just sent `mkdir project`, which doesn't produce any output.

Comment: Also, `proc.stdout.readlines()` reads until the subprocess closes the pipe. But it won't do that until the shell process finishes.

Comment: Maybe you should be using `pexpect`.

Comment: @Barmar I'm not executing the script directly because I want to intersperse the commands with their output in what the program prints. (And this is actually a subset of the real project which is outside the scope of the question. The real project intersperses the commands and their output with Markdown to create an article.)

Comment: There's no way to know where the output of each command ends.